# Erro de permissão e erro 403 no Git push

Tags: git

Estou tentando fazer um push para o meu repositório, porém, o git sempre me da esse erro:

> remote: Permission to danielswater/social.git denied to MichelleG-.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://usuario@github.com/usuario/social.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Eu não sei mais o que fazer, no gitconfig, esse usuário "MichelleG" não aparece. Já tentei também fazer o `git config --global user.name`, mas nada disso deu resultado. Alguém saberia me dizer como posso resolver isso?

Obs: Estou usando o Git no Windows

Comment: Talvez você precise colocar a senha ao lado do usuario, exemplo: `https://usuario:senha@github.com/usuario/social.git`.
Sugiro você configurar o ssh na sua máquina, assim fica mais simples.

Comment: Também não deu
Já tentei desinstalar o Git, removi tudo quanto era arquivo e nada. Já tentei clonar o projeto novamente, e nada

Comment: Essa máquina é sua ou da empresa?

Comment: Essa máquina é minha. Eu lembro que eu adicionei esse usuário para poder fazer um trampo p essa pessoa, só que agora não consigo mais remover. No gitconfig, ele nem aparece, aparece o meu usuário mesmo

Comment: Você adicionou como ssh?

Comment: Não, sem ssh mesmo

Answer (score 8):

Problema resolvido. Para isso, eu editei as credenciais do Github no Windows.

Se estiver no Windows 7, pode ir por esse caminho:

Painel de Controle\Contas de Usuário e Segurança Familiar\Gerenciador de Credenciais

Lá no final, você irá encontrar o item "Credenciais Genéricas" com o link do Github ou do Gitbucket ou dos dois Ai é só você clicar na setinha e editar o nome de usuário e a senha.

Comment: Estou com mesmo problema no Windows, poderia me explicar o passo-a-passo para ver se eu consigo corrigir aqui? Obrigado

Comment: Guilherme, se estiver no Windows 7, pode ir por esse caminho:
Painel de Controle\Contas de Usuário e Segurança Familiar\Gerenciador de Credenciais
Lá no final, você irá encontrar o ítem "Credenciais Genéricas" com o link do Github ou do Gitbucket ou dos dois
Ai é só você clicar na setinha e editar o nome de usuário e a senha

Answer (score -1):

Verifica no repositório se você tem privilégios de ADMIN.
Se estiver por exemplo como READ, você só poderá dar pull.