# Git - Error 403

Tags: git, github

Boa noite a todos.

Estou com um problema que não consigo dar o comando "push" no git bash. Sempre dá o "the requested URL returned error:403", pesquisei e achei uma solução que testei que é acessar o Gerenciador de Credenciais do Windows e remover a credencial do github. Fiz isso e ainda acontece o mesmo erro. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

**Código:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você não tem permissões para enviar alterações neste repositório. talvez você não configurou o email e a senha do github no git. / isso ajuda você? -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176978/erro-de-permiss%c3%a3o-e-erro-403-no-git-push